# Difference between AdomdConnection and AdomdCommand classes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mdx, olap, adomd.net

My understanding is that AdomdConnection initializes a connection with a remote database. This class opens it based upon the ConnectionString. The AdomdCommand then seems capable of setting a CommandText and Executing said command, similar to executing a query.

Is this understanding correct? But how are the two related? Do I initialize the AdomdConnection, then initialize AdomdCommand.Connection to this value? Is this how AdomdCommand knows what open connection to use or where the database in?

I have been using these two sites for reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdcommand.aspx

Comment: Read the two pages you linked.

Comment: I wouldn't have posted this question if I hadn't. I've read through them thoroughly. I don't have much c# experience or experience using databases. I'd appreciate some help rather than some patronizing response.

Comment: I just can't believe that you don't see a [`Connection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdcommand.connection.aspx) property in the [`AdomdCommand `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdcommand.aspx). I guess reading really _is_ a lost art.

Comment: Did you see [ADOMD.NET Client Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123477.aspx)? I've never used this API or done any ADOMD programming, but it's pretty easy to find links to the correct information.

Comment: You don't have to be a dick about it dude. Why is it so hard for you believe that I couldn't understand the documentation myself as it is?

Comment: It's easy for me to understand that. I'd love to know what part you didn't understand, and what could have helped you understand. Is there some chance that you're in beyond your depth? See [“You're Unclear on What You're Asking”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291866/youre-unclear-on-what-youre-asking).

Comment: BTW, it's not that I'm being a dick about it. It's that I'm not letting you off the hook, and I'm willing to be called a dick if necessary, in order to help you find out what it is you don't understand. See [the one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291866/youre-unclear-on-what-youre-asking) about the guy who had to take Calculus 101 four times before passing.

Comment: Having read the links you posted, I stick by my initial assessment of you. My questions weren't overly broad or unanswerable. They might've been simple but I explained my understanding of the problem and showed I put in effort. And given the answer below, I was even partially right. You really weren't trying to help me so don't lie to yourself.

Comment: I was trying to help you answer your next five questions. You may have the immediate answer to your immediate question, but you have not learned what it was that kept you from seeing the answer on your own. As a result, you'll have the exact same problem the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use CreateCommand() from the connection object, you would then get a command with the Connection property already set to the Connection from which it was created, or create the Command separately (new AdomdCommand()) and set its Connection property.

Either approach would work.
As to the actual connection to the database, it does not happen when you create the connection object but rather not until you call the Open() method on the connection object.